# Get data from database and append data to aframe

Tags: html, aframe

I want to get data from database and append that data to aframe. I did and data is getting from the database but not appending to the aframe scene. Here is my working flow.
This index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene id="scene">
    <a-camera id="camera" position="0 0 2" >    
    </a-camera>
  <a-sky color="#000"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
<script>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var method = "GET";
    var url = "data.php";
    var asychronous = true;

    ajax.open(method,url,asychronous);
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(data);

            var html = "";
            var username = "";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                username = data[i].username;
                html += "<a-scene>";
                html += +username;
                html += "</a-scene>";
            }

            var totalText1 = document.createElement('a-text');
            totalText1.setAttribute('position',{x:0, y:0, z:0});
            totalText1.setAttribute('color',"#fff");
            totalText1.setAttribute('value',username);
            totalText1.setAttribute('scale',{x:1.6, y:1.6, z:1.6});
            document.getElementById("scene").appendChild(totalText1);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is `data.php` file

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

$query = "SELECT * FROM usertest WHERE language='english'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $data = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Data retrieving is okay.But is there any way to append those data to aframe scene?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the entity is actually getting appended to the scene. It looks right. Check the Inspector (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>i</kbd>) or DOM Inspector or query selector from console. The 0/0/0 position might just make it hard to see.

Comment: Yes I checked with that also. But that does not work.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Does your A-Frame code ever run? Does it append anything to DOM? Do you see anything in Inspector? What do you see when you log stuff?

Comment: Yes function is working. A-Frame and ajax function are working. I tried to  get value from database and append it to aframe scene. aframe scene is showing and I saw DOM to check ajax function is working or not then I saw it's working but the value which I got from database that does not append to the scene or does not show. I want to do like filtering. But does not work.

Comment: Sorry, will need more details than "does not work" or "does not append" to help. I asked several questions above related to logging.

Comment: I am giving answers of your questions. 
Yes A-Frame code run. aframe scene showed. 
In DOM `Object
language
:
"frence"
username
:
"alex"
__proto__
:
Object` this one is showing.
In inspector it showed camera, sky, entity and text is showing. Here is the screen shot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1puPHy46eyGGllwsu1e2GtxXPSjCpzbOc/view?usp=sharing
And log staff means?

Comment: Alright, so it is appending. Make sure the scene is loaded when trying to append (`loaded` event, check `scene.hasLoaded`). You can try using text component form instead (more reliable) `setAttribute('text', {value: username...})`.

Comment: Yes I have used `scene.hasLoaded` In console it's showing loaded. and I used `setAttribute('text', {value: username...})` but the value of text does not append to scene.